# Can't Create Facebook Ads API Adgroup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying to use the facebook ads api to create an adgroup but the following code gives me the error 'invalid parameter'

```
$adgroup = new AdGroup(null,$account_id);
$adgroup->setData(array(
  AdGroupFields::CREATIVE => 
    array('creative_id' => $creative->id),
    AdGroupFields::ADGROUP_STATUS => AdGroup::STATUS_PAUSED,
  AdGroupFields::NAME => 'My First AdGroup',
  AdGroupFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $adset_id,
));

$adgroup->create();
echo 'AdGroup ID:' . $adgroup->id . "-";
```

Comment: Looks like recommendation from docs are to initialize create with fields instead of set data.
`$fields = array(
  ....
);

$ad = new AdGroup();
$ad->create($fields);`

Comment: now, it gives error: parent id is required

Comment: Sharing the complete example as provided in the docs - 
`use FacebookAds\Object\AdGroup;
  use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdGroupFields;

  $fields = array(
    AdGroupFields::NAME => 'My Ad',
    AdGroupFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $adset_id,
    AdGroupFields::STATUS => AdGroup::STATUS_PAUSED,
    AdGroupFields::CREATIVE => array(
      'creative_id' => $creative_id,
    ),
  );

  $ad = new AdGroup();
  $ad->create($fields);`
Source - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adgroup/v2.3

Comment: as i said before, still gives that error